# stencil config copy - 'copy' does not exist in type 'StencilConfig'

Tags: javascript, typescript, stenciljs, stencil-component, stencil-compiler

How can I use **'copy'** in stencil config, I am trying to make all ***i18n.json*** be available after compilation.

```
export const config: Config = {
  namespace: 'components',
  plugins: [
    ...
  ],
  outputTargets: [
    ...
  ],
  copy: [
    {
      src: "**/*.i18n.*.json",
      dest: "i18n",
      warn: true
    }
  ],
};
```

Error:

> copy: { src: string; dest: string; warn: boolean; }[]; }' is not
> assignable to type 'StencilConfig'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy tasks have been moved into the output targets (I think in version 1). So simply move the copy task into one (or more) of your output targets.

```
export const config: Config = {
  namespace: 'components',
  plugins: [
    ...
  ],
  outputTargets: [
    {
      type: 'www',
      copy: [
        {
          src: "**/*.i18n.*.json",
          dest: "i18n",
          warn: true
        }
      ],
    }
  ],
};
```

Here are the docs: https://stenciljs.com/docs/copy-tasks#copy-tasks-for-output-targets